# Как сделать клик по блоку video-card-list.active?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Здравствуйте, как сделать клик по блоку video-card-list.active?**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо поместить внутрь тега

```
<a href="url">
   ...
</a>
```

а **url** уже подставить нужный.

Либо обрабатывать click элемента и из JavaScript вызывать

```
window.open(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelector(".video-card-list.active").click();
```

---

Установка события клик на элемент:

```
document.querySelector(".video-card-list.active").addEventListener("click", () => alert(111));
```

Comment: Не работает либо я не понял как его внедрять... именно чтобы при клике открывалась ссылка

Comment: @VIGA "как сделать клик" и "чтобы при клике открывалась ссылка" - разные вещи

Comment: Понял, а как сделать так чтобы открывалась ссылка?

Comment: @VIGA какая ссылка?

Comment: Ссылка генерируется из базы данных с помощью php (href="single.php?id=<?php echo $single["id"]; ?>)

Comment: Но для примера можно любую ссылку к примеру.. https://vk.com/feed

Comment: @VIGA обернуть в тег ```<a>``` http://htmlbook.ru/html/a